Downloading OSM data for whole of Netherlands via Geofabrik
I need shapefile data for roads and railways in the Netherlands. I can use https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/netherlands.html to download several files. However I can only data for each province (region) but I need the shape file data for the whole country.
I do not know which data format I need to download, where do I need to look?

you have to download the subregions and merge as the "netherlands-latest-free.shp.zip is not available for this region; try one of the sub-regions."

There may be too much data to fit into a single shapefile. The format has a 2 GB size limit. Dowload the netherlands-latest.osm.pbf instead.

Try merging in a GeoPackage can be up to 140TB
